# error with code to auto rename a folder of CSV files

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, file-rename

The code is meant to auto rename a bunch of `CSV` files which are called

```
history (1) ... history (42)
```

here is the events list:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5bJvxM9TZkhYXZOSnRDVnhTbFk

Here is a screen shot of the files in my folder:

[image: screen shot]

The new names are captured from a web page through Beautiful soup. The new names have two possibilities in format most of them have `two` sections and only four have `three` sections.

When it comes to the rename function I encounter an `error`.

Here is the whole code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

events = open('events.txt', 'r')

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Sayed\\Downloads")


# name
for event in events:
    sauce = urlopen(event).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find_all('title')
    for x in title:
        title = x.text

    try:
        firstName, lastNmame, country = (title.split('-'))
        firstName = firstName.strip()
        lastNmame = lastNmame.strip()
        country = country.strip()
        name = ('{} - {} - {}'.format(country, firstName, lastNmame))
        for file in os.listdir():
            firstName, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            os.rename(firstName, name)

    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        firstName, country = (title.split('-'))
        firstName = firstName.strip()
        country = country.strip()
        name = ('{} - {}'.format(country, firstName))
        for file in os.listdir():
            firstName, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            os.rename(firstName, name)

    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

 File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/Tutorial/pan.py", line 37, in <module>
    os.rename(firstName, name)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file  specified: 'history  (1)' -> 'European Monetary Union - Services Sentiment'
```

Comment: the error says it all.."FileNotFound".

Comment: the file is exist

Comment: Trust the error. Check for the value of "firstName" and "name".

Comment: i am sure the files is exist you can look at the image above

Comment: os.rename expects file name with extension. but your firstName contains only file name "history (1)" and not the extension. it should be "history (1).<extension here>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It's working!

I replicated your entire setup, with all the `history (x)` files and everything and managed to write the code that **works**.

Here it is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

events = open('events.txt', 'r')

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Sayed\\Downloads")

for i, event in enumerate(events):
    sauce = urlopen(event).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

    title = soup.find_all('title')[0].text.strip()

    filename = "history ({}).csv".format(i+1)

    newName = "{}.csv".format(title)

    os.rename(filename, newName)
```

#### How does it work?

First of all, we `import` all the necessary `libraries` as before.

We then open the `events.txt` file which contains all the `links` to the pages where we want to extract the `titles`.

We then enter the main `for-loop`. What we are looping through here may seem a little strange if you haven't seen it before, technically we create a `list` of `tuples` from the `events` where the first `element` of the `tuple` is the `index` and the second `element` is the value - so here, it is the `event`. To give an example so you understand this completely:

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> for i, ele in enumerate(l):
...     print(i, ele)
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

So now, we have two `variables` to work with: the `event` (so the `link` to the page) and the `index` of that `event` out of all the `events`. Remember, as Python `lists` are `0`-based, the `index` will go from `0` to `42` (not `1` to `43`) so when we use this to rename the `files` later on, we must remember to add `1`.

Next, we get the `raw data` from the `link` that is this `event` with `urllib`. Then, we extract the `title` from the `event` using `BeautifulSoup`. This is done by finding *all* of the `'title'`s in the page and taking the first one by indexing it with `[0]`. We need to `index` it like this as `soup.find_all` returns a `list` of length `1` and we want the first `element`. We then take the `.text` of this to get a `string` and do a `.strip()` on the `string` to get rid of the carriage return and newline characters (`/r/n`).

Next, we define a `variable` called `filename` that will store the name of the `file` that we currently want to `rename`. We get the `name` by simply taking the `history (x).csv` bit which is the same for all of the `files` and formatting this with the `index` of the current `event` (`file`) that we are working on - note that we `format` with `i+1`, not `i` as the `files` start at `history (1).csv` not `history (0).csv`.

We then define a variable called `newName` which is simply the `filename` that we want to `rename` to. The name of this is just the `name` that we extracted before (the `title`) and then `'.csv'` on the end as we need to keep the `file` `extensions` the same.

Finally, we do the `rename` call for this `file`. This is simply the `filename` to the `newName`!

---

This definitely worked for me so I don't see any reason why it shouldn't for you... Also, I hope you understand everything that the code is doing, and just ask in the comments if I missed something...

Comment: i did what you just suggest and i got this error

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/Tutorial/pan.py", line 26, in <module>
    os.rename(firstName +ext, name + ext)

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'history  (11).csv' -> 'European Monetary Union - ZEW Survey - Economic Sentiment.csv'

Comment: FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:

Comment: @sayedgouda see the updated answer, `shutil.move` should fix that `error`... Please up-vote and accept if it does:

Comment: @ Joe Iddon i did what you say and the result is deleting all the files but one.
then rename it and rename it again and again till the list of names ends

Comment: @ Joe Iddon i replaced the os.rename with the shutil.move and the result is deleting all the files but just one remain in the folder and this single file keep changing its name till the script stopped

Comment: @sayedgouda something weird seems to be going on, try assigning `os.listdir()` to a `variable` before the `for-loop`. It could be the case that renaming them is effecting the iteration over the directory...

Comment: @ Joe Iddon sorry sir i do not know how to do that

Comment: @sayedgouda Don't worry, I think I found the problem! You are trying to `rename` all the `files` to the same thing (`name`).... This just won't work, you need to name them different things!

Comment: @ Joe Iddon is there any pythonic way to finish this job i mean the (name) is a function that produce different string every time so there is no duplicates or missing files.

Comment: @sayedgouda I think you are slightly confused with things, you assign `name` to a fixed `string` before the `for-loop`, so it does not change during the `renaming` of the files... Thus all files end up with the same name and there is only one visible file at the end

Comment: @sayedgouda I have to go, but if you post the `events.txt` file in your question, I will look at it properly in the morning and try and get it working for you :)

Comment: @sayedgouda I managed to write it after all! It took a while, but should work now!

Comment: @ Joe Iddon thanks again for answer and for the explanation, but I have a question Just for curiosity, what if the files have different names?
How to deal with it?

Comment: @sayedgouda well Python needs to know which file to rename to what, so they have to follow some kind of format so here it is `history (x)` but you could easily modify the `code` for a different format... And what happened to the `up-vote`? **:P**

Comment: sir about the up-vote i tried that but the site respond is i have reputation less than 15 so i can NOT up vote any thing, but i promise you that i will up-vote your answer as soon as i pass the reputation thing.

Comment: @sayedgouda thank you! Is the code definitely working for you now?